# Any way to keep shape name in a new slide?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I have a macro that lets me insert a text in a text box in all slides, just by entering the text and the shape name. The problem is that when I insert a new slide with a placeholder the shapes in that new slide lose their name, even when I name then in the slide master. Is there a way for the shapes to keep their name when I insert a new slide?

Comment: I don't think what you're describing will work as is, but since you've posted no code, it's impossible to say. Show us a simplified example of the code in question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but the problem is not the code. I need to keep the shape name even when inserting a new slide so the program can read it properly, but instead it just gets inserted as "Text shape 1" and such. It wouldn't be a problem if it was constant on every slide but some get more text than others so the program fails.

Comment: I think you'll need to describe the problem more clearly. When I insert a new slide, the placeholders keep the same shape names as they have on the layout.